# Java web application DAO writing authenticated UserID and IP Address to DB

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

I'd like to write to my Oracle DB the user ID and IP address of the logged in user (web app) whenever I perform SQL UPDATEs and INSERTs. Such as

```
public static int updateUser(STKUser user, STKUser loggedIn) throws DAOException {
  Connection connection = null;
  connection = DB.getConnFromCache();

  PreparedStatement ps = null;

String query = "INSERT INTO xtblPersonnel (pID, pPssWrd, pAdminDate, pAdminIP, pAdminBy) VALUES (?,?,SYSDATE,?,?)";
  try {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, user.getBadge());
    ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
    ps.setString(3, loggedIn.getIpAddress());
    ps.setString(4, loggedIn.getBadge());
    return ps.executeUpdate();
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("SQL Exception inserting new user with badge: " + user.getBadge() + ". Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
     LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "SQL Exception inserting new user with badge: " + user.getBadge() + ". Error Message: " + e.getMessage(), user);
     throw new DAOException("SQL Exception inserting new user!");
     // return 0;
  }

  finally {
     DB.closePreparedStatement(ps);
     DB.releaseConnToCache(connection);
  }
```

}

STKuser is a Javabean

My application uses a general Oracle db username and password so that is the reason why I want to record who did the update or insert and from which machine.

Is this an acceptable approach.  I used to pass in the session but have realized this is a no no.

Comment: Difficult to tell from the given information. Why 2 STKUser objects? They seem to be representing the same user is my guess. Where are you initializing the PreparedStatement and the Connection? Where is the catch block? Why is this method declared static?

Comment: one STKUser object was representing the employee data being added to the database and the second STKUser object was representing the administer logged in doing the SQL INSERT. I've edited my answer to include more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're properly closing all DB resources as `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` in the `finally` block of the `try` block where you acquired them and the code is doing what it should do, I don't forsee problems with the approach in question. There is no risk for SQL injections since you're using `PreparedStatement`, if that was your actual concern. Declaring the method `static` is however a bit a smell, but then we need to know more about the context the code is running in.

Comment: Static because method is just CRUD.  But I'm still learning J2EE. The way I call it, eclipse prompted me to change it to staic.
if everything is good on the form then I call:

STKUserDAO.insert(formUser, loggedInUser);